# `return_if(cond, val)` without resorting to macros

Tags: c++, gcc

I'd like to create a `return_if(cond, val)` without resorting to macros, for using in non-static member functions. It should be equivalent to

```
{
    //do some stuff on non-static data members here
    if (cond) return val; //and don't return otherwise
}
```

I don't mind using GCC extensions. It will appear frequently in the code, so I'd like a terse thing.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (cond) return val;`? You're not really saving any typing by doing `return_if(cond,val);`

Comment: What would the function return if `cond` is false? Maybe you want [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: `if (cond) return val;` is the clear and idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: The only way for a function call to cause the calling site to not continue is to terminate or throw. Terminate obviously won't work here and you certainly don't want to start using exceptions for basic flow control just to subjectively pretty up a function call.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Any such machinery that isn't a macro (which you've ruled out) or a new keyword (which you cannot create) will necessarily have its own function scope.

Even if you could, you shouldn't. Just do as everyone else does, and use the conventional, widely-understood, normal way:

```
if (cond)
{
   return val;
}
```

If your function has an unmanageable amount of branches and `return` points, perhaps it's time to revisit the design of your function.